# How can same controller be used to return different views?

Tags: laravel, view, routes, controller, laravel-8

I have one controller class. The index function returns all cd and book products. The main admin can view all products. I have used same controller for CdAdmin but cdAdmin should only be able to view cd products. In controller view is returned for admin showing all products. How can the cd products be shown for cdAdmin by using same controller?

ProductController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $book = Product::where('type', 'Book')->get();
        $cd = Product::where('type', 'cd')->get();
        return view('mainAdmin/products',['Book'=>$book, 'cd'=>$cd]);      
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/products',[ProductController::class, 'index'])->middleware('role:admin');
Route::get('/cdproducts',[ProductController::class, 'index'])->middleware('role:cdadmin');
```

Comment: you should seperate the two controllers, not just the method, make a seperate folder for each role. Admin/ProductController.php and Cdadmin/ProductController.php that way you will avoid a lot of if/else and keep your code maintainable (do it for all controllers)

Answer (score 1):

you can use get params like `?type=book` or `type=cd` in same url

```php
Route::get('/products', [ProductController::class, 'index'])->middleware('role:admin');
```

in controller

```php
public function index()
{
    $type = request('type'); // this will be getting from url ?type=

    if($type == "book"){

    }
    if($type == "cd"){

    }    
}
```

then for book url will be

```php
/products?type=book
```

and for cd

```php
/products?type=cd
```

---

for role base you can use like this

```php
public function index()
{
    $role = auth()->user()->role; // you have to create this to get role

    if($role == "admin"){

    }
    if($role == "cdadmin"){

    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Role based worked and solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can create method for each middleware or
you can set user type in your middleware request:

in middleware:

```
$request->request->add(['role' => 'cdadmin']);
```

and you can use this in controller

```
$products = ($request->role === 'cdadmin') ? Product.... : Product;
```

regards

Answer (score -1):

why don't you pass the `user-id` with the route and check in the controller, if you have stored role_id in the DB against a user:

```
public function index($id)
{
    $role_id=DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->value(role_id); //will give you role-id against that user
    if($role_id==1)
  {
    //for admin
    return view();
  }
else
  {
    return view();
  }
    
}
```